# any python lightweight gui library?

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, pyqt

I've tried using pyinstaller to package a simple hello world example using both pyqt and wxPython and both of them were about 15mb to 20mb. Why is it so big , its not practical for simple apps. Is there any other cross-platform solutions?

Comment: Give `tkinter` a try?

Comment: It is a pity that this question got closed. Just yesterday I compared size, distribution size (packed) and memory used by simple apps created in `PySide`, `wxPython` and `tkinter`. Obviously `tkinter` wins all the size aspects. `tkinter` is usually considered ugly, but I have just recently found that there are themed widgets included in `ttk` library included which improve the look significantly. I recommend http://www.tkdocs.com for learning Tk.

Comment: Stackoverflow: the place where your questions are closed rather than answered... This is a valid and interesting question. On topic: Tkinter is very good, not so fancy though. I'm in search for a lightweight chart (compatible with tkinter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For small applications you should take a look at `Tkinter` (or `tkinter` in python3). As it is part of the standard library, your clients don't have to install an additional library to use the graphical interface. IDLE, the ide which comes with the standard installation of python is written in tkinter for example.

To get started with tkinker, https://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter is a good point to start.

Comment: man this creates a 350 mb file any other way to get small pack