# Which cross platform GUI toolkit to use if less resource consumption is a priority

Tags: python, user-interface, widget

I believe the tittle itself is sufficient.

I'm currently learning GUI programming using Tkinter in python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [any python lightweight gui library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20294471/any-python-lightweight-gui-library)

Comment: Is tkinter not working from you?

Answer (score 1):

I actually wanted to comment this (but seems like i don't have enough reputation), so here is a simple breakdown.

**tkinter** is a really nice library (it's beginner friendly - fairly customized), I will highly recommend sticking with tk (because u r already learning it - it will totally comply with your requirement of less resources' consumption ).

I would suggest you to give a try to kivy - **if and only if** u wish to target mobile devices - it allows native development. Although it uses fair amount of resources which might -in some cases- overlook your system resources.

NOTE: Having said that, if you you require apps with powerful GUI experience, **PyQT** is definitely a better choice but from what I know, PyQt may not be able to fulfill your priority of less resources' consumption.

Comment: The question is specifically asking about libraries that use less resources. Do you know if kivy uses less resources than tkinter?

Comment: @BryanOakley

 Of course not. tk is definitely a better choice. I suggested to give kivy a try if and only if he desires to target mobile devices. I will update the answer to make the same more clear to the OP. Thanks for the suggestion :)

I myself use tk/tcl.

Comment: I fell in love with Tcl about five minutes after learning it. I've never found another language that fit my brain after learning it. I wish I could find a tcl/tk gig, but they dried up a decade or two ago.

Comment: I would totally agree. I do all my GUI work in tk.
It is just so amazing and efficient.
and after additions like ttk (although I don't really use ttk much as I am able to customize styles in tk only ), it has become more awesome.

Comment: Sometimes I wish, tkinter allowed us to do packaging for Android and iOS.